# Typescript Deprecation warning

Tags: angular, typescript, subscribe

I am using this code for login but subscribe shows depricated. I am new to typescript, so can anyone help me out

```
doLogin() 
{
  
     this.userService.doLogin(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
     result => 
     {
     console.log(result);
     localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(result));
     this.router.navigate(['/list-user']);
     this.toastr.success('Success', 'Logged In Successfully');
     },
     (error) => 
     {
     console.log(error);
     this.toastr.error('Failed', 'Invalid Credentials');
     });
}
```

this works in an other project I've worked on but shows depricated here
and I'm getting this error:

@deprecated — Instead of passing separate callback arguments, use an observer argument. Signatures taking separate callback arguments will be removed in v8. Details: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

'(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | null | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | null | undefined): Subscription' is deprecated.ts(6385)
Observable.d.ts(55, 9): The declaration was marked as deprecated here.

Comment: Please add the error you are seeing.

Comment: Please update your question with this error.

Comment: please add code after formatting

Comment: code formatting is necessary

Answer (score 2):

As per the link

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
// recommended 
of([1,2,3]).subscribe((v) =>         
console.info(v));
// also recommended
of([1,2,3]).subscribe({
    next: (v) => console.log(v),
    error: (e) => console.error(e),
    complete: () =>     
        console.info('complete') 
})
```

You will no longer need to pass more than one callback.
If needed you can pass in an observable object containing the callbacks.