# Rxjs subscribe deprication

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

After going through a tutorial, I noticed the 'subscribe' was being deprecated.  I tried following https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments and some stackoverflow questions like [Typescript Deprecation warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330414/typescript-deprecation-warning) but was not able to update to the new approach.

I've include the code in question. Any help pointing out where I went wrong porting the deprecated approach to the new approach would be appreciated.

```
public books: Book[] | undefined;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) {}

  ngOnInit() { this.getBooks(); }


  public getBooks(): void{
    // Reference: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

    // **deprecated:** This work, and I can see this.books has values
    // this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe(
    //   (response: Book[])=>{this.books=response},
    //   (error: HttpErrorResponse)=> {alert(error.message);}
    // );


    // **New approach**  This compiles but value is undefined.
    of([this.bookService.getBooks()]).subscribe({
        next: (value:any) => {
          this.books=value;
          console.info("Next: "+value.text); //console shows value is undefined
        },
        error: (value) => {
          alert(value.message);
        },
        complete: () => {
          console.info('complete');
        }
      }
    );
```

```
export interface Book{
  title: string;
  author: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the error here is that you wrapped `this.bookService.getBooks()` inside an array. If you remove the square brackets it should work.

Also you don't need to use `of()` here. Just subscribe as normal.

```
this.bookService.getBooks().subscribe({
  next: (value) => {
    this.books=value;
    console.info("Next: "+value.text); //console shows value is undefined
  },
  error: (value) => {
    alert(value.message);
  },
  complete: () => {
    console.info('complete');
  }
});
```